# Which JS datetime picker handles DST transitions properly?

Tags: javascript, timezone, datetimepicker, dst

I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle local date times in the frontend of my app.

I want to find a JS datetime picker that is timezone aware (uses moment.js) and handles DST transitions correctly (ie: doesn't let you choose a 00:00 if it doesn't exist on the day chosen and lets you choose between both 11:00 pms which occur on the same day by showing both instances with some sort of visual cue that there has been a DST transition).

Is there any advice or best practice for handling DST transitions in time pickers ? I can't seem to find any.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Great idea! But AFAIK this doesn't exist as any sort of pre-canned component.  I've always had to author this myself, and it ends up being specialized for each application.  I've not taken the time to write a generic version that could be used in any application.

You could certainly author it as a moment.js plugin.  We'd be glad to link it from the momentjs.com web site.  Please let me know if you decide to do that.

In terms of general advice for a time zone aware date/time picker - I think you got most of it, but to recap:

- Disallow an invalid date/time to be selected for the target time zone.

  - You might show a popup, or validation error, or just block out the selection so it can't be picked.  Or a combination of these approaches.
- If an ambiguous date/time is selected for the target time zone, ask the user which of the two instances they meant.

  - Store this in full ISO8601 extended format, such as `2013-11-03T01:00:00-05:00`.
  - It would be interesting to see if you could represent this selection visually somehow.  perhaps with two selections showing the offset (-04:00/-05:00) and/or the abbreviation (EDT/EST).
- If you need to pick a time zone also, keep in mind that the full list of IANA time zones can be intimidating, with over 500 entries.

  - You might want to offer a *pair* of drop down lists, one for the country, and then one for the time zone that is filtered by country.  You can use [zone.tab](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/zone.tab) data to filter by country code.
  - An alternative approach would be to incorporate a map-based timezone picker, such as [this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).
  - You might consider using [jsTimeZoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) to guess at the local time zone.
  - Of course, you might just want the target time zone to be provided separately so the developer implementing your control can decide how to wire up the time zone selection.

Comment: Visually, I'd show the offset with a message "On this day, the clocks will go back 1 hour. This is after the transition.", unfortunately, at the moment I don't have time to implement this, but I'll look into it real soon (in a few weeks). Normally, I want such a control to be passed to it the IANA timezone id (which would be passed to the internal moment.js instance).

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.  You might consider something like how they are listed on [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=179).  Also, you will definitely need [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to make this work.